# How to test mouse scroll event on flutter widget tests?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I've wrapped up `PageView` widget inside a `Listener` widget. There I check in `onPointerSignal` property if `pointerSignal` is `PointerScrollEvent` to detect if the user used the mouse wheel to scroll on the widget. Then instead of doing the weird behaviour it produces I `animateToPage` and I set `physics` property of the PageView to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` so it does not interfere with `animateToPage` transition.

That is working really cool! It jumps from one page to another with a smooth animation by moving mouse wheel.

But fun comes when testing the behaviour through widget testing. Does someone know how to emit/dispatch a `PointerScrollEvent`? I've tried the following without any success.

```
void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'when mouse wheel moved forward then next page is shown',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        Test(
          child: PointerAwarePageView(
            children: [
              Text('1'),
              Text('2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

      expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);

      tester.dispatchEvent(
        PointerScrollEvent(scrollDelta: Offset(0.0, 1.0)),
        HitTestResult(),
      );
      await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 3));

      expect(find.text('2'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Does it help you? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/gestures/gesture_binding_test.dart

Comment: @Akif unfortunately not, in that test they are not actually triggering the event. I need to know whcih specific function from ```WidgetTester``` allows me to fire a ```PointerScrollEvent```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to do it. This flutter test inspired me:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/scrollable_test.dart#L316

We need to create a `TestPointer` with mouse device kind and perform scroll. Then send the event though `WidgetTester`.

I will write down here my working resulting test:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets(
    'when mouse wheel is scrolled then next page is shown',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        Test(
          child: PointerAwarePageView(
            children: [
              Text('1'),
              Text('2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

      expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);

      final Offset scrollEventLocation = tester.getCenter(find.byType(PointerAwarePageView));
      final TestPointer testPointer = TestPointer(1, PointerDeviceKind.mouse);
      testPointer.hover(scrollEventLocation);
      final HitTestResult result = tester.hitTestOnBinding(scrollEventLocation);
      await tester.sendEventToBinding(testPointer.scroll(const Offset(0.0, 1.0)), result);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.text('2'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```